# Laravel: Is it possible to log stack trace when exception caught, and continue the execution?

Tags: php, laravel, exception, error-handling

Laravel has readable log and stacktrace when exception caught, for example:

```
production.ERROR: Command "test" is not defined.

Did you mean this?
    make:test {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Exception\\CommandNotFoundException(code: 0): Command \"test\" is not defined.

Did you mean this?
    make:test at {root}/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:618)
[stacktrace]
#0 {root}/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(229): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->find('test')
#1 {root}/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(148): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#2 {root}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(88): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#3 {root}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(121): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#4 {root}/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#5 {main}
"}
```

The question is: is it possible to catch the exception myself, and log the same format of the stacktrace, and continue the program execution. By far, I am logging the error by `Log::error(json_encode(debug_backtrace()));` which is really ugly and hard to trace. The example code:

```
try {
    foo();
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    Log::error(json_encode(debug_backtrace()));
}
bar();
```

Comment: Here is a better way to log the debug_backtrace `\Log::error(debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 15));`

Comment: 'json_encode' is not needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laravel has a helper method just for this, see the [rescue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-rescue) method.

```
return rescue(function () { 
    return $this->method(); 
});
```

Using your example it would look like:

```
rescue(function () { 
    return foo(); 
});

bar();
```

Comment: That's help. The `rescue` method recently add on Laravel 5.5 and hope they will add a section to take about it in their error handling doc. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: Yeah this is a really eloquent [pun intended!] answer, so I removed mine ;-)

Comment: This is pretty ugly and non-intuitive.

Answer (score 15):

You can simply call your app's exception handler manually:

```php
<?php
try {
    foo();
} catch(\Throwable $e) {
    report($e);
}
bar();
```

Introduced in Laravel 5.5, [the `report()` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-report) gives you the same error reporting you'd normally get, including any customizations you may have made for additional logging channels, etc.