# In Laravel, Why Not Logging debug in "laravel-xxxx-xx-xx.log" file automatic when something evokes exception..?

Tags: php, laravel, logging, try-catch

I wrote in controller like this

```php
try {
    $this->notice->create($notice);
} catch (\Exception $exception) {
    return response()->json(['result' => false, 'message' => 'Error.'], 409);
}
```

but in "laravel-xxxx-xx-xx.log" file, There wasn't happened anything.

Of course, I found this

```php
try {
    $this->notice->create($notice);
} catch (\Exception $exception) {
    \Log::error($exception);
    return response()->json(['result' => false, 'message' => 'Error.'], 409);
}
```

but i don't want to write that \Log::error($exception) in every controller..

Is there anything way to solve it..?

Thank you.

Comment: Because you're catching the error in your try catch which is causing it to not be reported. By catching it, you're telling your application that you are going to handle the exception from there on causing it to not bubble up to the applications error handler

Comment: If you want it logged, you can use the Log facade as you've found, or [report it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56674379/1376624)

Comment: Thank you for your help :)
I should execute what your suggestion.